# Will the front facing camera work with ARCore

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Is it possible to use the device's front facing camera with `ARCore`?  I see no references in Google's docs.

Comment: What would be the use case for this?

Comment: @StevenMohr - Think creating experiences like Snapchat using ARCore.  Thanks for the comment

Comment: Check this medium article I wrote for switching cameras or working with the front-facing camera for ARCore android [here](https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any reference in the docs. It would also make the whole AR process much more complicated. You have to invert the logic for moving the camera etc. And it's much harder to recognize planes as the user is always in the way. Right now, ARCore only recognizes planes so you can't detect feature points, e.g. in the face of a user.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is: Yes**.

With a front-facing camera (without a depth sensor) on any supported Android device you can track users' face since ARCore 1.7 SDK release. The API allowing you to work with a front-facing camera was named [Augmented Faces](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-faces/). So, from now you can create a high quality 468-point 3D mesh that your Android app can overlay on a user’s face to bring fun animated effects.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to work with faces, but if it possible to work not with faces? I mean if is it possible to use selfie camera as back camera for AR? It is interesting... Thanks

Comment: At the moment you can use front-facing camera only for Augmented Faces API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to make front camera use in ARCore SDK android

Create a customARFragment.kt file

```
package com.example.artry

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import com.google.ar.core.Config
import com.google.ar.core.Session
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment
import java.util.EnumSet


class CustomArFragment : ArFragment() {

    override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session?): Config {
        val config = Config(session)
        config.updateMode = Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE
        config.focusMode = Config.FocusMode.AUTO
        config.instantPlacementMode = Config.InstantPlacementMode.LOCAL_Y_UP
        config.depthMode = Config.DepthMode.DISABLED

//        config.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED
        config.lightEstimationMode = Config.LightEstimationMode.DISABLED
        config.augmentedFaceMode = Config.AugmentedFaceMode.MESH3D

        session?.configure(config)

        this.arSceneView.setupSession(session)

        return config
    }

    override fun getSessionFeatures(): Set<Session.Feature?>? {
        return EnumSet.of(Session.Feature.FRONT_CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
//        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val frameLayout =
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState) as FrameLayout?
        planeDiscoveryController.hide()
        planeDiscoveryController.setInstructionView(null)
        return frameLayout
    }
}
```

Now to use this

```
var arFragment: CustomArFragment? = null
arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment) as CustomArFragment

        arFragment?.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult, plane, motionEvent ->
            val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()

            loadViaAssets(anchor)
        }

private fun loadViaAssets(anchor: Anchor) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, Uri.parse("andy.sfb"))
            .build()
            .thenAccept { modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor, modelRenderable) }
            .exceptionally {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setMessage(it.message).show()
                return@exceptionally null
            }
    }


    private fun addModelToScene(anchor: Anchor?, modelRenderable: ModelRenderable?) {
        val anchorNode = anchor?.let { AnchorNode(it) }
        val transformableNode = TransformableNode(arFragment?.transformationSystem)
        transformableNode.scaleController.maxScale = 3f
        transformableNode.scaleController.minScale = 0.8f
        transformableNode.renderable = modelRenderable
        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
        transformableNode.rotationController.isEnabled = true
//        transformableNode.localRotation = arFragment?.arSceneView?.scene?.camera?.localRotation
        arFragment?.arSceneView?.scene?.addChild(anchorNode)
        transformableNode.select()
    }
```